# Turn-by-turn navigation for trucks problem with STARTER plan from HERE

Tags: android, navigation, here-api, turn-by-turn

I would like to implement **Turn-by-turn navigation for trucks** function for my android mobileAPP.

As a test, I tried to make work the following code example containing :
https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/turn-by-turn-navigation

I subscribed to the **starter plan from HERE** and downloaded the associated SDK package.

When I try to make it run, it says that we are missing the following package : `com.here.android.mpa.guidance.NavigationManager`, especially `guidance`.

When I look at the package, I notice that the libs folder doesn't contain anything (please refer to the image) [content of the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arAgb.png)

Can anyone please help me sort the issue out ?

Best regards

Comment: Did you do step 6 of the readme? Where it says you should copy a jar to your libs folder?

Comment: Yes I have added the jar that I downloaded from Here account to libs folder, but "guidance" cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1):

All truck features and also all TbT navigation features are only available in the Premium package. See the differences of Starter and Premium on the Mobile SDK main page, there's a comparison table of the features: https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks